# Animation from table is gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I reloaded table when i receive message .

here is code :

```
[self.tblChatting beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:app.Glb.arrayChat.count-1 inSection:0];
[self.tblChatting insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[indexPaths copy] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.tblChatting endUpdates];

[self.tblChatting reloadData];
[self.tblChatting scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath
                        atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                animated:YES];
```

and here is my table view object detail when animation not in there and my row is not added to table :

```
    <UITableView: 0x18bece00; frame = (0 55; 250 351); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = 
<NSArray: 0x17ec5fb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x17ec5150>; contentOffset: {0, 6541}; contentSize: {250, 6892.0312}>
```

and here is table view object when row is added succesfull and animatoin in object :

```
    <UITableView: 0x14949e00; frame = (0 55; 320 351); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x14665210>; animations = { position=<CASpringAnimation: 0x1a75d9f0>; bounds.origin=<CASpringAnimation: 0x1a4e9d20>; bounds.size=<CASpringAnimation: 0x1ac4b980>;
 bounds.origin-2=<CASpringAnimation: 0x1a1fbb40>; bounds.size-2=<CASpringAnimation: 0x1a1b02d0>; }; 
layer = <CALayer: 0x145f1300>; contentOffset: {0, 6593}; contentSize: {320, 6944.1309}>
```

and it happen sometimes only.
Why this happen ?

Comment: remove, table reload.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the line

```
[self.tblChatting reloadData];
```

`insertRowsAtIndexPaths` rearranges the table view implicitly.

Delete also the `begin/endUpdates`lines. They have no effect for a single insert operation.

Answer (score 0):

It happen you insert the row in table view as well as you reload the table:

Try this:

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:app.Glb.arrayChat.count-1 inSection:0];

[self.tblChatting insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPaths] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

[self.tblChatting scrollToRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath
                        atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom
                                animated:YES];
```